# How labels are maps in Pandas MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this data set,

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame( { 
    "Country" : ["C1", "C2", "C1", "C3", "C1", "C3", "C1"],
    "City" : ["ISB", "KHR", "LAH", "DUB", "RWP", "RWP", "RWP"],
    "Sales" : [10, 25, 40, 20, 45 , 43,10]  } )
```

on which i did this;

```
grouped_new_df = new_df.groupby(['Country', 'City'])
new_new_df = grouped_new_df.agg({'Sales': {'Mean': np.mean, 'Sum':np.sum}})
```

[image]

```
new_new_df.index
MultiIndex(levels=[['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['DUB', 'ISB', 'KHR', 'LAH', 'RWP']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 4]],
           names=['Country', 'City'])
```

Here I don't understand how these labels `labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 4]],` are mapping ?

Comment: map of levels with range of len

Answer (score 5):

The `labels` are the respective indices of your `levels`. For instance, the first level of your multiindex in `Country`. If you look at the `levels` for that, it is 
the list comprising `C1`, `C2`, and `C3`. So your data is `C1,C1,C1,C2,C3,C3`, *i.e.* indices `[0,0,0,1,2,2]` of the list `[C1,C2,C3]`.

Same logic applies for the `City` levels

Comment: I understand the logic of Country, but for City, it should be `[ISB, LHR, RWP, KHR, DUB,RWP] = [0,1,2,3,4,2]` ? but the output says it is ` [1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 4]`,

Comment: Looking at your dataset, it should be `[ISB, LAH, RWP, KHR, DUB, RWP]`, which is indeed indices `[1,3,4,2,0,4]` of the list `['DUB', 'ISB', 'KHR', 'LAH', 'RWP']`

Comment: does it follow any sequence (sorting), as DUB is at 4 row index, they what it has 1, how does it exactly map, reading from first row ISB = 0 index, LHR = 1 , RWP = 2 and so on?

Comment: This is speculation, but in your case it works (which makes me think it is what is happening): it returns the [`lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) order of your original `Country` and `City` columns in your `new_df`: check this by doing: `np.lexsort((new_df.Country, new_df.City))`, and this gives you `array([3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5])`, *i.e* the indices of `new_df.City` corresponding to the list `['DUB', 'ISB', 'KHR', 'LAH', 'RWP']`

Answer (score 1):

In your example , if you want the value of `index` `level=1` , you can .

```
new_new_df.index.levels[1][new_new_df.index.labels[1]]
Out[230]: Index(['ISB', 'LAH', 'RWP', 'KHR', 'DUB', 'RWP'], dtype='object', name='City')
```